# Naming convention for ways of defining direction

Tags: coordinate-system, gis-principle, direction, terminology

The following two conventions for defining direction are very common, but what are they called?

- 0 at north, clockwise
- 0 at positive x-axis, counterclockwise

Background: I'm writing a function that converts direction from one convention to the other, and struggle to come up with a good and clear name for it.

Comment: I'd use "bearing" and "angle", respectively, but I suspect this is more of an opinion than an Answer.

Comment: For the first, "azimuth" can also be used. The second is more a convention from mathematics / trigonometry I suppose - not so common in mapping.

Answer (score 2):

For a "0 at north, clockwise" variable or function, consider labeling it as Cardinal, as the following article on Cardinal Directions discusses the very degree notation you've just described:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction#:~:text=The%20ordinal%20directions%20(also%20called,%2C%20and%20northwest%20(NW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction#:%7E:text=The%20ordinal%20directions%20(also%20called,%2C%20and%20northwest%20(NW)) .

For "0 at positive x-axis," counterclockwise, I would label it as Cartesian, as it mimics the the X-Y plane most often used in math classrooms.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system